# How to read characters in a string and return depending on input?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

This is what I have: I want to make a program that asks the user for an input: your name.

This is what I need help with: Then, I want the program to read every character, letter, in the name. Lastly, I want it to return a list of adjectives corresponding to each character in the user's name.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    System.out.println("This program will give meanings to every "
                        + "letter in your name.\n");

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
    String name = input.next();

    String A = "adventurous";
    String B = "bold";
    String C = "caring";
    String D = "devoted";
    String E = "encouraging";
    String F = "funny";
    String G = "gentle";
    String H = "honest";
    String I = "intelligent";
    String J = "joyful";
    String K = "kind";
    String L = "loving";
    String M = "mature";
    String N = "neat";
    String O = "organized";
    String P = "persistent";
    String Q = "quick";
    String R = "religious";
    String S = "sensitive";
    String T = "thankful";
    String U = "useful";
    String V = "virtuous";
    String W = "witty";
    String X = "this letter isn't in your name";
    String Y = "young";
    String Z = "zany";  
}
```

Comment: You need more tags.  What language is this?  I think it's JAVA but does everyone else know?

Comment: What output/error are you seeing?

Comment: @WillSheppard I only get the two print statements:
"This program will give meanings to every letter in your name."
"Please enter your name."
When I enter my name and hit enter nothing happens since the code is incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your adjectives in a Map (with the char as key and adjective as value) instead of using those strings, then convert the name to a CharArray, iterate over it and for each letter just fetch the item from the Map. You can put your adjectives into a List and then print them later.

```
//create the map and the list of adjectives
Map<Character, String> adjectives = new HashMap<>();
List<String> personAdjectives = new ArrayList<>();
//fill the map (although it would be better retrieving data from a database)
adjectives.put('a',"adventurous");
adjectives.put('b',"bold");
// ...
//convert the name to a char array
char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
//iterate over it
for(char c : chars){
  //access the map and fill the list
  personAdjectives.add(adjectives.get(c));
}
//print the list
```

Comment: I get an error with:
"Map<char, String>..." - It says that I have to insert "Dimensions." I searched and changed it to:
"HashMap<String, Character>..." - Will that be fine with what you suggested?

Comment: Yeah, but you have to invert the order. I've updated my answer with the correct order.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Apparently I have to make a Char class as well though.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I wrote the code in a hurry and I made some mistakes. Actually I meant char instead of Char... You could use Character as well, and Java will automatically handle the casting. Anyway, I'm glad I could help you. Please take a moment to accept this answer if your program is running ok. You can do that by clicking on the green tick under the score of the answer.

Comment: `java.lang.Character` is the object version of the primitive `char`, there is no `Char`. You can't have a primitive `char` as key in a `Map`.

Answer (score -1):

#I hope this can help #

#### I don't have enough time, so summerized this code, you can work in your own

```
import java.io.*;

public class StringRead
{
    
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        
        String hi = "hi all man and sexy.";
        
        for(int x = 0; x < hi.length(); x++){
            
            System.out.println(hi.charAt(x));
            
        }
        
        
    
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to write a proper answer, for reference see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This answer doesn't have an explanation (see also [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/5698098)) while the given code does *not* really provide an answer to OP's question because it requires the OP to guess what he needs to do or fix with his given code.